# When is it advantageous to create a class in java

Tags: java, performance, class, jsf-2

I am creating a webapplication which has around 20 managedBeans for an equal number of jsf pages. Each page has a number of tables on the page that may/may not have the same column definitions. In this case, is it more efficient to create fields in the bean for each column or create a separate class for each table, populate the object of that class and then pass the object to the page?

Comment: just create another class and inherit that class

Comment: I can only inherit a single class. What if my page has 3 tables  and i have a class for each table.

Comment: How is this not a constructive question ? Its a very specific query and I was just expecting a suggestion as to which one of the two I mentioned is a better approach in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

We should always prefer to go with 1 bean per table approach. It will make the handling easier. In future also, if you implement Hibernate or any ORM tool then it will be easier if you have one bean per table.

However, you have to manage the dependencies among the table by inserting appropriate references/lists into the beans. 
E.g. if a person has multiple vehicles then person bean should have a reference of List.

Comment: So, you mean if I have 20 pages and each page has a minimum of 2 tables, I would end up having 40 beans (at the max) counting at 2 beans per page.

Comment: Yes. But, do you want to display the data from all the 40 tables in a single page?
Agreed that you will be having 40 beans but they will not get loaded unless you query the database on their respective tables.